# How to create a Typescript Set of classes inherited from a specific class?

Tags: typescript, generics, inheritance

I would like to create a `Set` of Widget-"derived" classes (not objects) in Typescript, but `Set<typeof Base>` doesn't seem to work when the subclasses have a constructor with any params:

```
class Base {}
class Child1 extends Base { constructor(id: string) { super(); } }
class Child2 extends Base { constructor() { super(); } }
const s = new Set<typeof Base>()
s.add(Child1) // fails: Argument of type 'typeof Child1' is not assignable to parameter of type 'typeof Base'
s.add(Child2) // works
```

Is there some way to get the limit correctly?

Comment: You say that the reasons are obvious and barely worth mentioning, but... I must be oblivious because [I don't see](https://tsplay.dev/wjnOvw) why `Set<typeof Base>` doesn't work.  What, specifically, goes wrong with `Set<typeof Base>`, and can you make sure the code here is a [mre] that demonstrates it?  (Also, what is "the `Child` class type"?)

Comment: I've updated the question with a reproducible example, thanks

Comment: So then your problem is with structural typing? [Empty example classes don't act how you want them to act](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely).  If you [fix that](https://tsplay.dev/WGVoJm) then does your problem just go away?

Comment: hold up, there seems to be two minimal examples that reproduce different issues. The above is only one of them, now working on adding another example

Comment: empty classes might be the reason I don't see the real issue, with non-empty classes I do get the original problem, I'll update shortly

Comment: I've updated the example, how it reproduces the issue

Comment: What are you going to do with the class constructors in that set?  Just use `instanceof` on them?  Or will you actually construct anything with them? If you're not constructing anything with them then [this](https://tsplay.dev/wgZpbW) might work for you.  If you are then the error is a necessary one since some of those things cannot be constructed the way you want.  Let me know how to proceed.

Comment: I was only planning to perform `s.has(Child1)` so your solution seems to work, thanks :-)

Comment: You should still not use empty classes in your examples, since they again would end up allowing everything, and you don't want that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would like to say "any constructor which produces instances of a type assignable to `Base`". For this you'd use a [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) of a form `new (???) => Base` where the `???` has to be replaced with the constructor arguments we want to support.  Since you don't care about actually constructing things, you don't want to be restrictive at all.  The way to say that is `new (...args: any) => Base`.  Let's test it out:

```
class Base { a = 1 }
class Child1 extends Base { b = 2; constructor(id: string) { super(); } }
class Child2 extends Base { c = 3 }
const s = new Set<new (...args: any) => Base>()
s.add(Child1) // okay
s.add(Child2) // okay

class ChildBad { z = 5 }
s.add(ChildBad) // error!  
// Property 'a' is missing in type 'ChildBad' but required in type 'Base'.
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFNoG9pmgXmgRmgXwChRIYBhACwEsQATXBADwBcEA7GmeCJVAI02gAmANzRgAe1YQmAJwCuwJuJkAKSjQBc0aTMqsA5gEoU2uQAcEqw6Lz4i4KNArUag6IxbtOiE8AEBmOwkpJm0BVgQAd2gAZQQmAB4I6JUAOnSwGX0ILTBWAE9jDAA+OERilUMCCFSwGhoVZ1psYwB6VuhxAGswfOra+saqWkE2ju7egnsSJ2GaeBoTAC8BAFY7GrqGpvm6sfcZGWUAQmhoAAUjixkmfOgAcjB76EoYAFtXiD19F9ZoW4sDx2C2evDkoRkCAAjnJKJDFnp-vlAfcuAh7qkpkA)